# How to disable Android Room from managing the schema?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm new to Android Room. I would like to use it to read and write to my Sqlite database. I do NOT want it to manage the schema (create/migrate tables).

First, I'm not completely sold on Android Room yet, so I don't want to commit to it by having it manage my schema.

Second, I prefer complete control over the schema.

I currently get a Room exception when starting the app. I assume this is because Android Room encounters my existing schema.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

How do I stop Android Room from creating/migrating tables?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the database schema, e.g. either entity or something else, you have to increase version here:

```
 @Database(entities = {Person.class, Product.class}, version = 2)
```

That's it.

On the other hand if this issue bothers you in development mode, just uninstall/install app, and the error will disappear. Or just clear app's **application data** from settings.

In other cases you have to manage migrations.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please, check the question. The problem is not the version number. The problem is that Room wants to version the schema at all. I want to manage my own schema and disable Room from changing/checking the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would like to stop auto generating database schema:

```
@Database(entities = {Person.class, Product.class}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
```

exportSchema will disable auto generating schema by default.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.

The documentation says this about exportSchema: "You can set annotation processor argument (room.schemaLocation) to tell Room to export the schema into a folder." Thus the flag seems to stop the schema file from being generated but not from the database tables getting created.

Comment: I think that what are you trying to do is complicated, you can just go to the implementation of your DAO classes and copy the autogenerated source code to have optimal sqlite request functions.After that remove Room from your project.

Comment: Note: typo in exportSchema